# Compiling .mex or .oct files using mkoctfile with Octave and Visual Studio 2010 Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, octave

I am trying to compile a basic c++ `.mex` and `.oct` file using the octave environment. The `.mex` file is just `mexcpp.cpp` file from matlab which you can get in MATLAB using

```
edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/mex/mexcpp.cpp']);
```

The `.oct` file is the simple c++ example on found [here].(http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Getting-Started-with-Oct_002dFiles.html)

I struggled for a bit with getting the visual studio compiler to setup all of the environment variables as documented on the [octave wiki using vcvarsall.bat](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Windows#Octave_with_Visual_Studio). Before the compiler environment variables were set up I could issue the `mkoctfile -v --mex mexcpp.cpp` command without any errors but no files were created.

Instead I had to specify the environment (I used x86) like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

Now the real problem I have been having is getting my `.mex` and `.oct` files to compile. When I try to compile the file I get:

```
cc-msvc -d -c -D_WIN32 -DWIN32 -D__WIN32__  -IC:\Octave-3.6.2\include\octave-3.6.2\octave\.. -IC:\Octave-3.6.2\include\octave-3.6.2\octave -IC:\Octave-3.6.2\include -Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include -Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include/freetype2 -Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include -Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include   -O2 -MD -EHsc -wd4244 -fp:strict -fp:except-   -I.  mexcpp.cpp -o mexcpp.o
cl -nologo -c -D_WIN32 -DWIN32 -D__WIN32__ -IC:\Octave-3.6.2\include\octave-3.6.2\octave\.. -IC:\Octave-3.6.2\include\octave-3.6.2\octave -IC:\Octave-3.6.2\include -Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include -Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include/freetype2 -Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include -Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include -O2 -MD -EHsc -wd4244-fp:strict -fp:except- -I. mexcpp.cpp -Fomexcpp.o mexcpp.cpp
C:\Octave-3.6.2\include\math.h(74) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'c:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include/math.h': No such file or directory cc-msvc -d -shared  -o mexcpp.mex  mexcpp.o   -Wl,-export:mexFunction -LC:\Octave-3.6.2\lib\octave\3.6.2 -LC:\Octave-3.6.2\lib -loctinterp -loctave -lcruft link -nologo -DLL -out:mexcpp.mex mexcpp.o -LIBPATH:C:\Octave-3.6.2\lib\octave\3.6.2 -LIBPATH:C:\Octave-3.6.2\lib octinterp.lib octave.lib cruft.lib -export:mex Function dirent.lib msvcmath.lib
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'mexcpp.o'
```

My Visual C++ directory is located in `c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC` so I am not sure why it is looking in `c:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that that the problem was in Octaves 'math.h' file. on line 74 the path to the include file is hardcoded to `c:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include/math.h`.
 I solved the issue by just changing to `c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include/math.h`. I tried compiling both the `.mex` and the `.oct` files and they now work!

Edit:

On another note I noticed that octave is also including hardcoded paths for some visual studio paths that don't exist.

```
-Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include -Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include/freetype2 -Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include -Ic:/Software/VC10Libs/include
```